# dotnetnuke localresourcefile does not return resource file name for dynamically loaded control

Tags: c#, module, localization, dotnetnuke

I am using DNN 7.04.

I am trying to get a string from a resource file and have tried these:

```
var path1 = Localization.GetString("MyAdsPath.Text", LocalResourceFile);
var path2 = Localization.GetString("MyAdsPath.Text", LocalResourceFile + "/AdditionalInfo.ascx.resx");
```

*path1* returns null and *path2* returns the correct string from the resource file.

In both cases *LocalResourcfile* returns:

/desktopmodules/qEmployerCreateAd/App_LocalResources/

The problem is I don't want to hard code the resource file name as it will change when the language changes.

I think the issue is to do with the control being dynamically loaded.
Do I have to check the culture and then hard code the resource file name? Or is there a better solution?

thanks
Norb

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this can be found in [DNNSimpleArticle](http://dnnsimplearticle.codeplex.com/)

But basically when loading the dynamic control, you just need to pass along the module configuration from the parent to it.

```
try
{
    var controlToLoad = "Controls/ArticleList.ascx";
    if (ArticleId > 0)
        controlToLoad = "Controls/ArticleView.ascx";

    var mbl = (dnnsimplearticleModuleBase)LoadControl(controlToLoad);
    mbl.ModuleConfiguration = ModuleConfiguration;
    mbl.ID = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(controlToLoad);
    phViewControl.Controls.Add(mbl);
}
catch (Exception exc) //Module failed to load
{
    Exceptions.ProcessModuleLoadException(this, exc);
}
```

Comment: thanks Chris. Neat. Any pro's with this over the BaseUserControl solution?

Comment: You don't need to override the files if you aren't changing the names, so no need to rename the LocalResourceFile path

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works:

http://weblogs.asp.net/anasghanem/fixing-dotnetnuke-localization-for-child-and-dynamically-loaded-usercontrols

In case that link dies here is the solution:

Create a base UserCotrol class that inherits from PortalModuleBase and fix the LocalResourceFile like below :

```
public partial class BaseUserControl :  DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules.PortalModuleBase
{
// basicly this will fix the localization issue 
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);
    string FileName =  System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(this.AppRelativeVirtualPath);
    if (this.ID != null)
        //this will fix it when its placed as a ChildUserControl 
        this.LocalResourceFile = this.LocalResourceFile.Replace(this.ID, FileName);
    else
        // this will fix it when its dynamically loaded using LoadControl method 
        this.LocalResourceFile = this.LocalResourceFile + FileName + ".ascx.resx";
}
}
```